# Display value converter for ASP.MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a few models that contain country ISO codes. I would like to display these with the actual country name instead of just the ISO value.

So in a generic sense, I have keys in my model, I have the definition of those keys in a dictionary, I would like to display the definition in the UI.

Having recently worked mostly in WPF, there I would create a converter which I could just reference in the UI binding whenever I wanted to translate a value (even bidirectional).  If there is a similar out-of-the-box concept in ASP.MVC that would be ideal.

Alternatively I *could* add the country names as attributes to the model, but that feels kludgy.

I could certainly roll my own custom converter solution, but would prefer to stick to best practices so any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: I would appreciate a comment for a downvote, how can I make the question better?

Comment: What about a custom attribute, like `DisplayValue`, that would change the displayed value based on a dictionary lookup? That would keep your code DRY

Comment: Not a down voter but I'll hazard a guess that it is to do with the lack of code in the question. Some people see no code, don't bother to read the question and just down-vote.

Comment: Thanks Jon P.  I also disdain 'do my work for me' sort of questions.  Trouble here is I'm looking for advise on directionally which way to approach the problem based on best practices before I try to throw some code together .  Appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A HtmlHelper might be an elegant solution for your problem.

First, you declare a HtmlHepler like this:

```
public static class CountryHTMLHelpers
 {
      //Initialize your dictionary here
      public static Dictionary<string, string> CountryDictionary;          

      public static IHtmlString ISOToCountry(this HtmlHelper helper, string iso)
      {
          string countryName = CountryDictionary[iso];
          return new HtmlString(countryName);
      }

      public static IHtmlString CountryToISO(this HtmlHelper helper, string country)
      {
          string iso = CountryDictionary.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == country).Key;
          return new HtmlString(iso);
      }
}
```

To use these helpers in your views:

```
@Html.ISOToCountry(Model.ISO) //Print the country
@Html.CountryToISO("England") //Print the ISO
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a try.  I'll need to provide the dictionary dynamically, but that should be simple, if I can do it via dependency injection on a static class is another story :)